# detatch windbg kernel debugger & keep target running

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, remote-debugging

Consider below scenario:

1. I have setup debug over serial port on a windows 7 system.
2. On another machine, I have installed windbg & connected serial cable between them.

When I start the target machine, & have windbg running on debugger machine, the connection between windbg & windows kernel gets established properly & I am able to debug as per what I want.

My problem is:

When the connection is established, there is no way to detatch the kernel debugging & allow it to run as stand-alone.
I often need to remove / re-install driver. Having the debugger attached is completely un-necessarily for this & it makes the installation very slow.

Simple solution is not starting windbg at all. But is there a way to just detatch debugger & allow the system to free-run, **after** the connection was established?
Currently, detatching the debugger keeps the target system in frozen state, allowing the user to be re-connected again.

NOTE: Any hacky way is welcome too. There is no clean way. (known to me at least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. I remember at some point (XP, maybe?) the target machine would time out after a while (30-60 seconds) and continue running, but I don't think that's true any longer.

Can you use .kdfiles instead of uninstalling/re-installing? Or, even better, switch to 1394.

Comment: I cannot use 1394, because it's not case of 2 simple systems. The target system is a virtual machine, connected using virtual serial-over-tcp, which is inherently slow.

Comment: Yikes... indeed. The target (win7_64) did timeout after ~100 seconds & started running. On another note, the target would freeze, ONLY when there was some logs being generated over the debugger port.

Comment: Nice! I could have sworn the timeout didn't happen anymore, but maybe it's just a serial debugging feature (I've been using mostly 1394 or VirtualKD only for quite a while)

Answer (score 0):

Usually on reboot it would be slow because it retrieves and loads all the symbols. Caching the symbols on host machine would improve the speed to some extent. And an another tip whenever you felt it got stuck or slower..is to press Ctrl + Brk to abort any long stuck loading operation and press F5 to continue run.

Comment: No, the symbols loading is done... I 'accidentally' started windbg (actually, by a script), which got attached to the target. target has booted to desktop & is usable as normal. However, because of debugger attached, everything is slow.